# Mitsubishi mirage Code P1590 A/T torque reduction req. comm

Tags: engine, electronic-control-module, mitsubishi

The check engine light on my mitsubishi mirage is on and upon scanning the codes, I am getting the following codes:

U0131 EPS CAN timeout

U0101 T/M CAN timeout

U0121 ABS/ASC CAN timeout

P1590 A/T torque reduction req. comm.

When i erase the codes, all go away except for the last one. I checked the battery terminals and fuses and they seem fine, i opened the Engine control unit and checked the connectors and it’s insides and they seem fine as well, no burns or anything unusual. What could be the problem?

Comment: I just read on a Mirage forum that people had this happen when they had a GPS or Bluetooth device hooked to the OBDll port.